# Extensible array of bytes

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an array of bytes that can be extended by adding more bytes to the end, similar to `vector<char>` in C++ or a byte string in Python.

A standard Java array and a `ByteBuffer` are both unsuitable because they aren't extensible.

`ArrayList<Byte>` would work but seems a little inefficient, as it would create a boxed object for every bite.

`StringBuilder` seems suitable (a `char` presumably has no difficulty storing numbers from 0 to 255), particularly since it can append several bytes in one statement, though its use for this purpose seems perhaps a little counterintuitive, as it was intended for text strings rather than binary data.

Is there anything else in the Java standard library that's better for this purpose than `StringBuilder`?

Comment: You could use an array and use the class `Array` to extend it when needed, but this is basically what an `ArrayList` does, so it's no more efficient really.

Comment: Do you need "random access" to the bytes? If no there is `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: Please take a look at [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

Comment: @AntonH uhmwell, not quite; as OP says, this has to create a boxed `Byte` for every `byte`, so it is quite wasteful memory-wise

Comment: You could just build your own optimized Wrapper class for an actual array of bytes which would handle the expanding of the array internally. I would probably recommend just using an ArrayList though. Why is it that the tiny performance hit from wrapping the objects is a problem? Sounds like you might be prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @fge True, but I rarely consider memory to be a problem for PC programming. Also, there may be optimised code that comes from standard libraries that he wouldn't have on customer wrapper. Otherwise, I agree with your comment.

Comment: @AntonH yes, those cases are indeed very rare; however I have had such a case to deal with quite recently... 80 million boxings per second become expensive ;)

Comment: @fge Yes, I see how that could be a problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

```java
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// invoke write(..) methods on baos.

final byte[] array = baos.toByteArray();
```